# Paypal sandbox not reflecting transactions in the response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-sandbox

On https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/ I have 2 sandbox accounts:
- [business] abc-facilitator@domain.com
- [personal] abc-buyer@domain.com

Then in the sandbox paypal store I login successfully with the buyer's account and click the continue button representing payment. I'm successfully redirected back to my success_url and receive what look like some successful params:

```
  /orders/success/6 token=SAME_TOKEN_FROM_PAYPAL_AS_THE_ONE_ABOVE&PayerID=THE_PAYER_ID_OF_SANDBOX_BUYER_ACCOUNT
```

Ok so cool the transaction is finished but when I log into the sandbox paypal site with either the buyer or seller's login details, no transactions are listed. When I'm logged into my main paypal developer account, I also cannot see any transactions.